# How to animate rolling of images (make 3d animated image)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a set of images of one item from different points and I need to make one 3d image from it with javascript. When I click on the button they roll in one direction, when another - to another direction. Is there any ready to use solution?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Take a look at [react-360](https://facebook.github.io/react-360/)

Answer (score 0):

I found ready to use solution. https://github.com/pisi/Reel